# "This app cant be installed because its integrity cant be verified" for iOS enterprise version

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Not able to install the enterprise version of the iOS app.[image]

Comment: Is the device on a private wifi without internet access?  The device must be able to communicate with Apples servers during installation and periodically during execution to validate the enterprise signing

Comment: @Paulw11, Device is on a healthy network. Trying to install an Enterprise app through a link. Then this error pops up.

Comment: Can you try via another network or 3G/4G connection?  This error typically occurs when the device cannot contact Apple's servers to validate the certificate chain.  It can also occur if your bundle isn't correctly signed, the provisioning profile is expired or the signing certificate is expired.

Comment: You can also check the device console log to see what is going wrong

Comment: @DhimanRanjit Do you able to fix this? I checked all reason that Paulw11 mentioned but my app doesn't have anything wrong.

Comment: Did you find a solution?